# How to get time of bar_index + 1 in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Is there a way I can access the time of the next bar index in Pinescript? I need it to work in the case when the market is closed as well. For example, if the market closed at 18:55 today (bar_index) then technically the time of bar_index + 1 should be tomorrow morning at 3:00. Another example, if the market closed at 18:55 today and it is Friday then the time of bar_index + 1 should be Monday at 3:00. How can I access the time of the next bar index even despite time jumps like this? I am currently doing something like `nextBarTime = time + ta.change(time)` to get the time of the next bar index but it doesn't work with these time jumps.

Comment: You have zero knowledge of the `next` candle when you are at the current candle, thus you won't make any trading decisions there or that's gambling. However you can always work with the previous candle and know how much time has passed.

Answer (score 0):

Technically there is no built-in function yet to get future time of the bar, you can write your own function which will add time offset to the current bar (and will take into account session, weekends and holidays).

(if you need to check if a new bar is from the new session you may use simplier solution to detect that: `session.isfirstbar` variable).